# In "The Time Traveler's Wife" why does Henry never meet himself?

Tags: time-travel, the-time-travelers-wife

There are several occasions in the Time Travellers Wife where Henry arrives at the same point as he's already been, such as when he sees himself die and when Alba is conceived.

Why does he never meet himself on these occasions?  Is there any other reason than the story would become too complicated?

Comment: Do you missed the scene where he meets himself after his mother's accident ? if yes then this question ssems wrong or incomplete

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure about the movie, but in the book he does meet himself a few times. I particularly remember an incident when teenage Henry met himself and decided to ... experiment.

Comment: ... It's not gay if it's with yourself... right?

Comment: LOL yeah. Dad caught them. It was a funny scene.

Answer (score 5):

In many books and movies dealing with time travel, there is the implicit (and occasionally explicit) 'rule' that the traveler *never* changes anything, because it may 'alter the course of history.'

Think Back to the Future, Hot Tub Time Machine, The Terminator, Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban and 12 Monkeys, just to name a few.

This 'rule' likely plays a role in Henry avoiding himself in the past, because he wants to be sure his future with Claire and the birth of their daughter all happen as he knows them to.

Answer (score 0):

In the movie, an older Alba met the younger one.  She appeared to to be explaining about death (looking at the dead bird), and possibly explaining about Henry impending demise.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the book, Henry meets himself at times, this is the part @SystemDown was referring to

> HENRY : I’m in my bedroom with my self. He’s here from next March. We are doing what we often do when we have a little privacy, when it’s cold out, when both of us are past puberty and haven’t quite gotten around to actual girls yet. I think most people would do this, if they had the sort of opportunities I have. I mean, I’m not gay or anything.

Page 42. I don't think this is in the movie, though.